# Using DropdownListFor - Value is being set using Jquery, Displayed in Console too, but Null at Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, drop-down-menu, model, html.dropdownlistfor

Here is the Syntax of My `Dropdown`.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DealerIdRef, Model.Ddllist, " Select Dealer ", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

i want its default selected value and make it read-only so that user can not update selection. For this i'm using `Jquery`.

```
$('#DealerIdRef').val('@Session["MyID"]').trigger('change');
$("#DealerIdRef").attr('disabled', 'true');
```

this is setting the  value and also exists in `Console`
[image]

At Controller it is still null
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

**Edit**

[image: image4]

if i'm making some mistake then please help.
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show your `model` code?

Comment: please check Edit @daniel.shih

Comment: I wrote a simple project for mock your Issue.I can get the value.
Are view's `model` and controller's receive  `model` the same?

Comment: yes. and can you please share that here in Code Snippet so that i can see. and find if i'm mistaking somewhere. also see that i'm using `DropdownListFor`. @daniel.shih

Comment: I upload my source Code,for your reference. @Divya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript is setting the `disabled` attribute of the dropdownlist. Disabled form controls do not submit a value so the value of `DealerIdRef` in your model is its default (i.e. `null` because its `int?`).

If you want the value of the dropdownlist to be submitted, do not disabled it.

But based on *i want its default selected value and make it read-only so that user can not update selection*, then there is no point generating a dropdownlist, and in anycase, you set selected option by setting the value of the property your binding to. That is you set the value of `DealerIdRef` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view.

Since all you want is to display a value and have it posted back, then include a hidden input for the value and display the text

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DealerIdRef)
<div>...the txt you want to display...</div>
```

There is no point degrading performance by generating a `SelectList` and extra html when its not needed.

As a side note, your POST method would have throw [this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) because you have not repopulated the `SelectList` in the POST method before you return the view.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple mock your question.

It can work. The simple code is on `DropDownController`

Here is the [Source Code](https://github.com/isdaniel/DropDownListForCode),I Upload to github.

**ViewModel**

```
public class DropDownViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Dealer")]
    public int? DealerIdRef { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Ddllist { get; set; }
}
```

**Index View**

Mock Your Submit action

```
@model Sample.Models.DropDownViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowDDL", "DropDown", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DealerIdRef, Model.Ddllist, " Select Dealer ", new { @class = "form-control" })
    <button>Submit</button>
}
```

**ShowDDL View**

Show your select data.

```
@model Sample.Models.DropDownViewModel

<b>Your Select Value: </b> @Model.DealerIdRef
```

**DropDownController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DropDownViewModel model = new DropDownViewModel()
    {
        Ddllist = GetDDL(),
        DealerIdRef = 1
    };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowDDL(DropDownViewModel viewModel)
{
    return View(viewModel);
}

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDDL()
{
    return new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = "One",
            Value = "1"
        },
        new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = "Two",
            Value = "2"
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What in the world does this have to do with the question (answer - absolutely nothing!)

Comment: You could take a look at the comment of the above question why I posted on this answer on here.I provide my simple code for the questioner.